pipenv - как использовать библиотеку уже установленную в другом окружении?
Использую pipenv, удобно.
Но не нашел ответа на вопрос: допустим у меня есть проект со своим environment, в котором установлено много библиотек.
Я начинаю писать другой проект, создаю для него новое окружение и хочу использовать какую-то библиотеку, которая уже установлена в другом окружении/или установлена глобально.
Логично конечно, не устанавливать эту библиотеку еще раз в новом окружении, если она уже ранее устанавливалась.
Как это сделать используя pipenv ?

нет, не логично. в этом и смысл окружения - "все своё ношу с собой".

логично с той точки зрения, что если библиотека занимает > 1Gb места на диске и она уже установлена (хотя бы и в другом env), правильно бы было иметь механизм ее использования в другом окружении, а не ставить ее заново
впрочем, вопрос был в другом - Вы точно знаете, что с pipenv это сделать невозможно?
